# Setting ADFS SSO

Tags: magento1.9.3.1

I'm trying to setup SSO for one of my Magento store. I'm using **OneLogin's SAML** extension for this

`(link for extension: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/saml-single-sign-on-extension.html)`

My client is asking for relying party identifier for SAML configuration on his side in ADFS. I have no clue what to give and how to setup this. I did search for that but no information found which will guide me to do this setup.

So if anyone have worked on this and can guide me through this..

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of the extension,

Relying party identifier = SP Entity ID, so what the ADFS administrator is asking is for the SP Entity ID, that can be found at your SP's metadata.
You will be able to get it accessing to the Magento's SAML Settings, at the Status section, you will find a link.

The SP Entity ID is configurable, and you can set any value at the "Advanced settings" section.

If you have any other info review first the documentation provided with the extension (You can also contact me by mail, provided in the documentation).

Comment: Thanks for the useful information. Will try it and get back to you in case of any further queries.